# Cannot parse the Android Application Modules gradle configuration.Resolve or resync

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, android-gradle-plugin, android-developer-api

Error: Could not parse the Android application Module's Gradle Config

I've been trying to setup Firebase in my Android project. Problem is, I've been getting this error: Could not parse the Android application Module's Gradle Config And I really can't solve it. I've seen quite a lot of people getting this error, can anyone help me understand how it will be fixedenter image description here

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

- Remove JCenter from gradle file

**Solution 2**

- Upgrade your dependencies with latest one.

**Solution 3**

- Define your sdk path in your environment variable

**Solution 4**

- Add this line in your gradle properties

  `android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=32`